# Using Collection Initializer with System.Data.DataTable.Rows

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

As far as I understand the use of a collection initializer is dependant on two things:

- The collection implements IEnumerable
- An Add() method

As far as I can tell `System.Data.DataTable.Rows` satisfies both of the requirements, therefore I would expect I could do this:

```
DataRow row = _dt.Tables["TABLE"].NewRow();

_dt.Tables["TABLE"].Rows =
{
    row
};
```

The compiler complains:

- Rows has no setter (but I'm not creating a new collection, merely adding to an existing one via the reference supplied

Perhaps you could point out my mistake.

**Update:**

I've just realised my issue is with `DataRowCollection` which doesn't implement `IEnumerable` but *does* have an `Add()` method.  Therefore am I correct in thinking that this doesn't work purely because `IEnumerable` isn't implemented?  If so why can't it be added to the BCL?

**Update:**

Please see this code that shows you can add to an existing collection with an initializer:

```
        public class Person
        {
            public Person()
            {
                friends.Add("Paul");
            }

            List<string> friends = new List<string>();

            public List<string> Friends
            {
                get { return friends; }
            }
        }

        Person tom = new Person
        {
            //Adding to an existing collection NOT creating a new one
            Friends = {"Steve", "Jim", "John"}
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Object and collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are only valid in "object creation expressions", which are introduced by the `new` keyword. From §7.6.10.1 of the C# 4.0 specification:

> *object-creation-expression:*
>      `new`   *type*   `(`   *argument-list<sub>opt</sub>*   `)`   *object-or-collection-initializer<sub>opt</sub>*
>      `new`   *type*   *object-or-collection-initializer*
>
> *object-or-collection-initializer:*
>      *object-initializer*
>      *collection-initializer*

And from §7.6.10.2:

> An object initializer consists of a sequence of member initializers, enclosed by `{` and `}` tokens and separated by commas.
>
> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the field or property.

So the following is a legal statement that creates a new `DataTable` and, using a couple of collection initializers, adds items to the embedded `Columns` and `Rows` collections:

```
DataTable table =
    new DataTable  // <-- IMPORTANT
    {
        Columns = { { "Name", typeof(string) } },  // table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        Rows = { "John" },                         // table.Rows.Add("John");
    };
```

In contrast, the following statement is not valid:

```
table.Rows = { "John" };
```

Although the expression resembles a collection initializer, it occurs outside the context of an object creation expression (there's no `new` keyword anywhere), and so the compiler parses the statement as `table.Rows = ...` instead of `table.Rows.Add(...)`.

In your original example, just call the `Add` method explicitly:

```
_dt.Tables["TABLE"].Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: According to page 222 of C# In Depth (Jon Skeet) this isn't true. Collection Initializers "Note that you're not creating a new collection here, just added to an existing one" [meaning when not using the `new` keyword].

Comment: No problem, I'll try to find a web reference.

Comment: Note the `new Person` in your example: *That's* what allows you to use object and collection initializers! If you don't have `new` at the beginning of the expression, then you can't use object and collection initializers.

Comment: Jon Skeet is correct as well. I don't have a copy of his book, but I fully expect the collection initializer is part of a larger `new` expression: he creates a new object and then adds an item to an *existing* collection on that *new* object. He isn't adding an item to an existing collection on an *existing* object.

Comment: I suspect you've hit the nail on the head there, my example was an adapted copy of Jon's so it would seem to hold water.